# Declaring multiple activities in the Android manifest

Tags: java, android, android-activity, switch-statement, android-manifest

I'm struggling with getting an activity to start from an options menu in my android app.

The option in question is for a help page.  The code I used for this (a switch case) is below and the help option is at the bottom:

```
@Override
// Respond to item selected on OPTIONS MENU
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    //put data in Intent
        case R.id.settings:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
    case R.id.easy:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Easy chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.medium:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Medium chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.hard:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hard chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.scores:
        Toast.makeText(this, "High Scores chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.help:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I think I have it set correctly in the manifest but when I click the help option, the app just crashes.  My manifest is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="cct.mad.lab"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="cct.mad.lab.MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GameActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
     </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HelpActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

I'm going to presume I've done something wrong that is obvious to others but I just can't see it right now.

Thanks for any help

EDIT:  I'm adding my HelpActivity class as I think it may be something that's not right in there.  I am a relative novice at this:

```
public class HelpActivity extends Activity {

public void init() {

    Intent helpScreen = new Intent(HelpActivity.this, MainMenu.class);

    startActivity(helpScreen);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.help_page);
    init();
}

InputStream iFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.gamehelp);

private String inputStreamToString(InputStream iFile) {
    TextView helpText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHelpText);
    String strFile = inputStreamToString(iFile);
    helpText.setText(strFile);
    return strFile;
}
}
```

Comment: What error does it give in logcat?

Comment: It doesn't give any as far as I can see

Comment: you said that when you click the button, app just crashes, so how it doesn't give you any error?

Comment: Looking in logcat there is nothing there for this time

Comment: then maybe there is something wrong in your HelpActivity java file or its layout file?

Comment: You may be right.  I've added this class in an edit.  I'm pretty sure the layout file is fine

Comment: again, it's hard to tell because after creating HelpActivity you instantly create MainMenu activity. Have you tried to remove init(); from onCreate() method and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem might be here:

```
Intent helpScreen = new Intent(HelpActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
 startActivity(helpScreen);
```

try to comment out this line in the onCreate method

```
 init();
```

It seems that you are trying to start another activity as soon as you start the helpActivity

Comment: Hmmm that doesn't work.  Do I need an 'setOnClickListener' in the HelpActivity class somewhere?

Comment: I had a hunch and just thought I'd try and comment out the InputStream iFile' bit and it now works so the problem is there.  Not sure what the problem is there but I'll take another look.  Sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with trying to add the raw resource file (.txt) to the layout.  When I commented this out it opened the activity fine.  So, that's another issue.